# Replace unwanted characters inside opening HTML tag only

Tags: php, html, iframe, replace, preg-replace

I need to do a little fix inside a script.

I need 2 specific characters (`“` and `»`) inside opening iframe tags to be changed into double quotes (`"`).

For example:

```
<iframe src=»http://test.test″>»hellohello»</iframe>
```

needs to become:

```
<iframe src="http://test.test">»hellohello»</iframe>
```

My code so far:

```
$content = preg_replace("/\<[“]\>/","\"",$content); 
$content = preg_replace("/\<[»]\>/","\"",$content);
```

But this is not working as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong regex inside.

```
$content = preg_replace("/\<[“]\>/","\"",$content);
```

Its mean that exactly:

```
<“>
```

will be replaced with quote. 
Working example from other site:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<([^<>]+)>/e', '"<" .str_replace(""", \'"\', "$1").">"', $content);
```

here str_replace is used and you can pass any quotes there.
You should do same thing with preg_replace_callback, its recommended for newer PHP versions (from 5.5 /e flag is deprecated).
Example (not sure its working, but you get the idea):

```
preg_replace_callback(
        '/<([^<>]+)>/',
        function ($matches) {
            return str_replace('OldQuote', 'NewQuote',$matches[0]);
        },
        $content
    );
```

Or with many different quotes create array:

```
preg_replace_callback(
        '/<([^<>]+)>/',
        function ($matches) {
            $quotes = array('OldQuote'=>'NewQuote','OldQuote2'=>'NewQuote2');
            return str_replace(array_keys($quotes), array_values($quotes),$matches[0]);
        },
        $content
    );
```

Comment: no problem, but i recommend callback, eval is not so nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

To replace one or more of the rogue, multibyte characters inside the opening iframe tag (in an HTML-ignorant fashion), you can call `strtr()` or `str_replace()` inside of `preg_replace_callback()`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iqrHN))

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/<[^>]+>/',
         fn($m) => strtr($m[0], ['»' => '"', '“' => '"']),
         $tests
     );
```

Or

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/<[^>]+>/',
         fn($m) => str_replace(['»', '“'], '"', $m[0]),
         $tests
     );
```

---

Because your HTML is "broken"/invalid, it s probably not worth trying to use a proper DOM parser to correct the markup.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```
$content = preg_replace('/<(.+?)(?:»|“|″)(.+?)>/','<\1"\2>', $content);
```

One single regexp, matching for anything containing `»` or `“` or `″`  between `<` and `>`.
Replaced with with `\1` (first capturing group). Followed by " and `\2` (2nd capturing group).

I hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

One solution is not to use preg_replace. 
You can simply use str_replace if the format is as you have described in question.

```
$str = '<iframe src=»http://test.test″>»hellohello»</iframe>';
$repl = str_replace(array('=»', '″>', '″/>'), array('"', '">'), $str);
print_r($repl);
```